Cross Correlation with Variable and Unsynchronized Sampling
I have two discrete signals that were not sampled at a constant rate and instead have a timestamp associated with each observation. The number of samples are large for each signal, but there are no timestamps in common between the signals.
The signals are actually the same (up to some noise), but with a time delay. I want to estimate this delay. Typically, I'd do so by finding the lag with the highest peak in the autocorrelation between the signals, but can't as the timestamps are not regular or synchronized.
Are there any other methods to estimate time delay? Is there a way to preprocess the signals to use the usual autocorrelation method?
